# Remove "type" from JSON output jersey moxy

Tags: java, json, jersey, marshalling, moxy

How to remove the `type` from the JSON output that I have.  I have a class/bean that contains output of a REST service.I'm using `jersey-media-moxy` to do the conversion.

The service

```
@Resource
public interface MyBeanResource
{
    @GET
    @Path("/example")
    @Produces( MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON )
    public Bean getBean();
}
```

The Bean

```
@XmlRootElement
class Bean
{
   String a;
}
```

I want to add some functionality (for initializing the bean using the constructor)

```
class BeanImpl extends Bean
{
    BeanImpl(OtherClass c)
    {
        a = c.toString()
    }
}
```

The outputted JSON is:

`{type:"beanImpl", a:"somevalue"}`

I do not want the `type` in my JSON. How can I configure this?

Answer (score 17):

I get the same error when I extend a class and generate JSON -- but only for a top-level (root) class.  As a workaround, I annotate my **subclass** with `@XmlType(name="")`, which prevents the generated `type` property from appearing in my JSON.

Blaise, I'm not sure why this works.  Any thoughts?

Comment: With the name attribute you probably override what would be written in the type property. Since you defined it as empty, Jersey skips the property completely.

Answer (score 3):

MOXy will add a type indicator to differentiate between the different subtypes.  This however will only happen if MOXy is aware of the subtypes (it isn't by default).

### Demo Code

**Demo**

Below is the equivalent code that Jersey will call on MOXy.

```
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.rs.MOXyJsonProvider;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MOXyJsonProvider mjp = new MOXyJsonProvider();

        BeanImpl beanImpl = new BeanImpl(new OtherClass());
        mjp.writeTo(beanImpl, Bean.class, Bean.class, null, null, null, System.out);

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
{}
```

### Possible Problem?

Do you potentially have an `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation on your real `Bean` class?

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlSeeAlso(BeanImpl.class)
class Bean
{
   String a;
}
```

Then the output will be (assuming `BeanImpl` also has a no-arg constructor):

```
{"type":"beanImpl"}
```

Comment: No. I don't have a @XmlSeeAlso.

Comment: I hit this problem just recently. Why does this happen only when marshallnig to JSON and not XML?

Answer (score 1):

You can build a custom message body writer .

```
@Provider
@Produces({
   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
})
public class BeanBodyWriter implements MessageBodyWriter<Bean> {

    @Override
    public long getSize(Bean t, Class<?> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // Called before isWriteable by Jersey. Return -1 if you don't the size yet. 
        return -1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isWriteable(Class<?> clazz, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType) {
        // Check that the passed class by Jersey can be handled by our message body writer
        return Bean.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(Bean t, Class<?> clazz, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
            MultivaluedMap<String, Object> httpHeaders, OutputStream out) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {

        // Call your favorite JSON library to generate the JSON code and remove the unwanted fields...
        String json = "...";

        out.write(json.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    }
}
```

Comment: That seems like overkill?

Comment: @RobAu Check my update, what is left is writing the `writeTo` method.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for elaborating. I still think it seems 'too much work' for the problem, indicating the solution will work, but is harder to maintain, etc. My alternative is a rewrite to a FactoryPattern and remove the subclassed-beans. I hoped for an eiasier annotation/configuration based solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to generate JSON and you won't have that problem:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: He's asking for moxy

Answer (score 0):

I used a Jersey specific Jackson package in a slightly different case, it worked. Detailed configuration is described in [Jersy document](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/media.html#json.jackson). In my case, I used a generic type field in an @XmlRootElement class. MOXy added a type in the JSON output. I can see why MOXy does it. If the JSON output needs to be unmarshalled back to a Java object, MOXy needs to know the type to create the correct object. However, in my case, the type is unsightly in the JSON output.